# Reload uicollection view controller from a button with in cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in a users friend request cell , when i decline it deletes their pending friend request from the database, it deletes the info from the database just fine but i can't access the `UICollectionViewController` that the cell belongs to,  to refetch pending requests from the database? hence it will fetch friend's request from the database and the one i just declined won't be there,  at the moment i have to leave the screen and come back for it to disappear?

Is it not possible to call a `UICollectionView`'s function from the button of a cell inside that `UICollectionView`?

```
protocol friendsRequestControllerDelegate {

    func fetch()
    }

    class FriendsRequestsCell: UICollectionViewCell, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

    var delegate: friendsRequestControllerDelegate?

    lazy var declineButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        b.setTitle("Decline", for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(declineFriendRequest), for: .touchUpInside)
        b.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        b.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

        return b
    }()

    func declineFriendRequest(){
        print("not yet set")
        guard let userAtRow = user?.uid else { return }

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }            

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Pending Requests").document(userAtRow).delete() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
                self.frc.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }

      delegate?.fetch()

      }    


    class FriendsRequestsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,friendsRequestControllerDelegate {

    func fetch(){
        firestoreFetchFriendsRequestsUserIds()
        viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    //collectionView?.reloadData()

     func firestoreFetchFriendsRequestsUserIds() {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Users").document(uid).collection("Pending Requests").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {   

                    let d = document.data()

                    d.forEach({ (key: String, value: Any) in

                        print("this is the key",key)

                        Database.firestorefetchUserWithUID(uid: key, completion: { (user) in

                            self.users.append(user)

                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        }    
                        )}   
                    )}   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some control element inside your collection cell (let it be a button). When you activate it (e.g. press the button), some process starts, and when it is finished, the collection view must be updated.

If that's the scenario you are facing (i.e. I understood you correctly), I'd do the following way:

1. Make a protocol for your cells:

   ```
   /// Used by cells to pass commands to their collection view
   protocol CustomCollectionViewCellDelegate: class {
       /// Requests the delegate to update data
       func reloadData()
   }
   ```
2. Modify your custom cell class to use the protocol

   ```
   class CustomCollectionViewCell: CollectionViewCell {

       // Some your stuff

       weak var delegate: CustomCollectionViewCellDelegate?

       @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
           yourAsyncProcess() {
               self.delegate?.reloadData()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Adopt the protocol by your collection view controller and add the following method:

   ```
   func reloadData() {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.collectionView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```
4. Set cells `delegate` property when updating cells

   ```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
   {
       let cell: CustomCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCustomCollectionViewCellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

       // Your custom cell setup setup

       cell.delegate = self
       return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: @vacawama Unfortunately, I still can't understand the difference between `strong` and `weak` pointers. Could you please explain why `delegate` pointer must be `weak`?

Comment: The collection view controller has a strong pointer to cell.  Your delegate is a strong pointer back to the collection view controller.  This strong retain cycle will keep them from being deallocated.  Just make the delegate weak and you avoid this situation.